# Ctrl + Shift + H cannot be detected using Me.KeyDown

Tags: vb.net

The code, which does not react during <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> is pressed :

```
Private Sub HideMode(ByVal sendeer As System.Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case CInt(e.KeyCode)
        Case Keys.ControlKey
            If e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyValue = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(Keys.H)) Then
                MsgBox("Test hide function")
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

The expected result is that, after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> a `msgbox` will show with text "Test hide function"

What's the error in here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't underdstand why you try to convert the KeyCode to an integer when the same work could be easily done using the Keys enum

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.H
        If (e.Control AndAlso e.Shift) Then 
            MsgBox("Test hide function")
        End If
End Select
```

**EDIT** Well, the WebBrowser control is a different beast. You need to add a specific KeyDown handler for it  (in addition to the other one that handles the KeyDown when the Focus is on other controls)

```
Private Sub Browser_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.H
            If e.Shift AndAlso e.Control Then
                MsgBox("Test hide function")
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set the Form KeyPreview = True? It seems that you want to handle the KeyDown for the form, not for a TextBox. This requires that property set to true

Comment: Where shold i set it?

Comment: Using the Form Designer. It is a property of the Form itself. You need it otherwise the keys go to the KeyDown event of the current focused control while it seems that you need a global catch on the form

Comment: No, I still can't use it. Is there another way to check Ctrl + Shift + H? There's nothing happening when I press Ctrl + Shift + H.

Comment: If you have another way, why not show it in the answer (what you said is `go to the KeyDown event of the current focused control while it seems that you need a global catch on the form`) and i don't really understand.

Comment: I don't have another way. It is just Me.KeyPreview = true in the Form_Load event (or using the form designer). I could show you a simple example made [using LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Is there anymore help??

Comment: A webbrowser requires additional steps. See the updated answer

Comment: Very good. I'm regreting that why I didn't give this code to you earlier.